# OpenGL view disappears while rotating

Tags: ios, ios6, opengl-es

I am using OpenGL 2.0 to draw a rectangle. Initially the viewport is such that i am looking from above and i can see my rectangle as i expected.
Then i start rotating this rectangle about the x-axis. When the angle of rotation equals -90deg (or +90 deg if rotating in the other direction), the rectangle disappears.
What i expect to see if the bottom surface of the rectangle when i rotate past 90deg/-90deg but instead the view disappears. It does re-appear with the total rotation angle is -270deg (or +270 deg) when the upper surface is just about ready to be shown.

How do i ensure that i can see the rectangle all along (both upper and lower surface has to be visible while rotating)?

Here' the relevant piece of code:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
    if ([touches count] == 1) {
        CGPoint currLoc = [touch locationInView:self];
        CGPoint lastLoc = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
        CGPoint diff = CGPointMake(lastLoc.x - currLoc.x, lastLoc.y - currLoc.y);

        rotX = -1 * GLKMathDegreesToRadians(diff.y / 2.0);
        rotY = -1 * GLKMathDegreesToRadians(diff.x / 2.0);

        totalRotationX += ((rotX * 180.0f)/3.141592f);

        NSLog(@"rotX: %f, rotY: %f, totalRotationX: %f", rotX, rotY, totalRotationX);

        //rotate around x axis
        GLKVector3 xAxis = GLKMatrix4MultiplyVector3(GLKMatrix4Invert(_rotMatrix, &isInvertible), GLKVector3Make(1, 0, 0));
        _rotMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(_rotMatrix, rotX, xAxis.v[0], 0, 0);
    }
}


-(void)update{
    GLKMatrix4 modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, 0, -6.0f);
    modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(modelViewMatrix, _rotMatrix);
    self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = modelViewMatrix;

    float aspect = fabsf(self.bounds.size.width / self.bounds.size.height);
    GLKMatrix4 projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(65.0f), aspect, 0, 10.0f);
    self.effect.transform.projectionMatrix = projectionMatrix;
}

- (void)setupGL {

    NSLog(@"setupGL");
    isInvertible = YES;
    totalRotationX = 0;
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    self.effect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];

    // New lines
    glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArray);
    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

    // Old stuff
    glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &_indexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _indexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Indices), Indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glViewport(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);

    // New lines (were previously in draw)
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid *) offsetof(Vertex, Position));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribColor);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribColor, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid *) offsetof(Vertex, Color));

    _rotMatrix = GLKMatrix4Identity;

    // New line
    glBindVertexArrayOES(0);

    initialized = 1;
}
```

I am a newbie to OpenGL and i am using the GLKit along with OpenGL 2.0

Thanks.

Comment: Possible causes are back face culling (which is normally disabled by default) or maybe lighting causes it to be completely black and be indistinguishable from the background.

Comment: The near clipping plane shouldn't be zero. Try changing it to `GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(65.0f), aspect, 0.01f, 10.0f);`. Also just `xAxis.v[0]` isn't correct in the rotation. `rotX` is the rotation and the next three values is the axis to rotate around. Try just `GLKMatrix4Rotate(_rotMatrix, rotX, 1, 0, 0);`.

Comment: @jozxyqk back face culling is enabled in my code. I have edited my question and added the 'setupGL()' method where back face culling is enabled.

Comment: @jozxyqk Thanks for the tips. But changing the near clipping to non-zero but positive value did not help. And neither did the changing the 3rd parameter to GLKMatrix4Rotate as you suggested. I have added my setupGL() as well, fwiw, to the question. Thx.

Comment: With back face culling enabled, polygons aren't rasterized from the back. `glFrontFace` determines which side of a triangle faces the front, `glCullFace` says which side to cull and `glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)` turns it on. Change to `glDisable` and your geometry will be visible from both sides, however your shader will need to accommodate that since your normals will only point in one direction.

Comment: @jozxyqk Thanks for the tip. Changing it to glDisable worked. You should make this the answer and i will accept it :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many causes for things not rendering in OpenGL. In this case, it was **back face culling** (see comments on the question). Back face culling is useful because it can ignore triangles facing away from the camera and save some rasterization/fragment processing time. Since many meshes/objects are watertight and you'd never want to see the inside anyway it's uncommon to actually want two-sided shading. This functionality starts with defining a front/back of a triangle. This is done with the order the vertices are given in (sometimes called *winding* direction). `glFrontFace` chooses the direction clockwise/counter-clockwise that defines forwards, `glCullFace` chooses to cull either front or back (I guess some could argue not much point in having both) and finally to enable/disable:

```
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE); //discards triangles facing away from the camera
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE); //default, two-sided rendering
```

Some other things I check for geometry not being visible include...

- Is the geometry colour the same as the background. Choosing a non-black/white background can be handy here.
- Is the geometry actually drawing within the viewing volume. Throw in a simple object (immediate mode helps) and maybe use identity projection/modelview to rule them out.
- Is the viewing volume correct. Near/far planes too far apart (causing z-fighting) or `0.0f` near planes are common issues. Also when switching to a projection matrix, drawing anything on the Z=0 plane won't be visible any more.
- Is blending enabled and everything's transparent.
- Is the depth buffer not being cleared and causing subsequent frames to be discarded.
- In fixed pipeline rendering, are `glTranslate`/`glRotate` transforms being carried over from the previous frame causing objects to shoot off into the distance. Always keep a `glLoadIdentity` at the top of the display function.
- Is the rendering loop structured correctly - clear/draw/swapbuffers
- Of course there's heaps more - geometry shaders not outputting anything, vertex shaders transforming vertices to the same position (so they're all degenerate), fragment shaders calling discard when they shouldn't, VBO binding/indexing issues etc. Checking GL errors is a must but never catches all mistakes.